# Not defined even though package has been imported

Tags: import, julia

I'm importing the Tensor Julia package like so:

```
julia> import Pkg; Pkg.add("Tensors")
  Resolving package versions...
No Changes to `~/.julia/environments/v1.5/Project.toml`
No Changes to `~/.julia/environments/v1.5/Manifest.toml`
```

Which shows no changes since it has already been installed once.

Then I call the Tensor function from this library:

```
https://kristofferc.github.io/Tensors.jl/latest/man/constructing_tensors/#Constructing-tensors

julia> Tensor{1,3,Float64}((1.0, 2.0, 3.0))
```

Which gives the error:

```
julia> Tensor{1,3,Float64}((1.0, 2.0, 3.0))
ERROR: UndefVarError: Tensor not defined
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at REPL[11]:1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think of `Pkg.add` as an installation step: you need to perform it once in the lifetime of the project, in order to let Julia (a) determine the version to be used and (b) download it to your machine.

In a second step, you need to tell Julia that you actually want to use functions from the package. And this is done on a per-module basis: not all parts of your program will necessarily need to use `Tensors`. This is performed using the [`using` or `import` keywords](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/modules/#Summary-of-module-usage), which are actually in charge of (a) loading the package code into your session for you to be able to call it, and (b) optionally bring into scope some of the functions defined in the package (in order to let you conveniently write e.g. `Tensor(...)` instead of `Tensors.Tensor(...)`).

```
# Installation step
# Do it once in the project lifetime (or each time you want to upgrade the version)
julia> using Pkg; Pkg.add("Tensors")
  Updating registry at `~/.julia/registries/General`
  Resolving package versions...
  Installed Tensors ────────────── v1.4.3
  [...]


# Code loading step
# You have to do it before using a function from the package
julia> using Tensors
[ Info: Precompiling Tensors [48a634ad-e948-5137-8d70-aa71f2a747f4]


# Now you can use all functions exported by the package
julia> Tensor{1,3,Float64}((1.0, 2.0, 3.0))
3-element Tensor{1,3,Float64,3}:
 1.0
 2.0
 3.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding and importing/using a package are two different things - you need to do

```
julia> using Tensors

julia> Tensor{1,3,Float64}((1.0, 2.0, 3.0))
3-element Tensor{1,3,Float64,3}:
 1.0
 2.0
 3.0
```

if you want to use the package!